# cannot get the session on vb page when it set using jquery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a img button. When it is clicked, I set the session value using jquery. however I cannot get the session on vb code behind. My process is like that after the user click the image, I set the session. When the user open popup page and return the page. I need to check the session to do something. However in the vb code, the session is nothing.  Would some one tell me how to do it.

The below code call the function:

```
<asp:Image ID="img" runat="server" onclick="SetSession(hdID);" ImageUrl="pic_bottle.gif" />
```

The jquery script:

```
function SetSession(hdID) {
    var hd = $('#' + hdID);
    var hdValue = hd.val();
    if (hdValue == "s") {
        $.session.set('UpdateProdOrder', -1);
    }
    else {
        var hdProdID = $('#hdProdID').val();
        $.session.set("UpdateProdOrder", hdProdID);
    }
    alert($.session.get("UpdateProdOrder"));
}
```

The vb code behind never get the session

```
If Not Session("UpdateProdOrder") Is Nothing Then
    'do something
    updateOrder() 
end if
```

Comment: While the answers below doubtless solve the specific problem, my guess is that the right thing to do is to redesign the data boundaries so that the client doesn't set session variables. See [Insecure Direct Object Reference](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Insecure_Direct_Object_Reference_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet).

Answer (score 0):

The localStorage and sessionStorage properties allow saving key/value pairs in a web browser.

The sessionStorage object stores data for only one session (the data is deleted when the browser tab is closed).

These values are maintained on the client side, but you are trying to retrieve it on the server side. session variables are server side

Solution:

**Method 1**:

You'd have to have a little ajax call to talk to the server to set it.
[please check it out](http://www.dotnetodyssey.com/2015/01/05/getset-value-session-variable-using-javascriptjquery/)

**Method 2** :

**Assigning the ASP.NET Session Variable using Javascrip**t.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function SetSession(hdID)
    {
        var hd = $('#' + hdID);
            var hdValue = hd.val();

      if (hdValue == "s") {

  '<%Session["UpdateProdOrder"] = "' + -1+ '"; %>';
            }
            else {
                var hdProdID = $('#hdProdID').val();

 '<%Session["UpdateProdOrder"] = "' + hdProdID+ '"; %>';
            }
         alert('<%=Session["UpdateProdOrder"] %>');
    }
    </script>
```

**Accessing ASP.NET Session variable using Javascript**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSession()
    {

        var updateProdOrder= '<%= Session["UpdateProdOrder"] %>';
        alert(updateProdOrder);
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a server side `Session` object with javascript directly. You need to send it to the server somehow. This can be done by changing the image to an `ImageButton` and do a PostBack to modify the Session object. But since you seem to have some data in `hdID`. You cannot send that to the server with a ImageButton alone, you'll need a `HiddenField`

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" runat="server" OnClientClick="SetSession(hdID);" 
    ImageUrl="pic_bottle.gif" OnClick="ImageButton1_Click" />

<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    var hdID = 'test';

    function SetSession(hdID) {
        $('#<%= HiddenField1.ClientID %>').val(hdID);
    }
</script>
```

And then in code behind

```
protected void ImageButton1_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Session["UpdateProdOrder"] = HiddenField1.Value;

    Label1.Text = string.Format("Session value is now '{0}'", Session["UpdateProdOrder"]);
}
```

You could do this also without the javascript `SetSession`, but that depends on where and when `hdID` is used on other parts of the page.